# Expandable cell, self sizing height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

I made expandable view with dynamic amount of `UILabels` (created progammatically according to the count of results query produces). However I am not able to resize the expanded view height according to how many `UILabels` I have in the expanded view.

Using `for loop` I make as many labels as there are results after query.

Now I put them into view like this:

```
for (index, _) in timesBetween2Stations.enumerated() {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
            cell.ExpandableView.addSubview(label)
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.center = CGPoint(x: cell.ExpandableView.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            var substationTime = timesBetween2Stations[index]?.time
            let substation = timesBetween2Stations[index]?.station
            substationTime = substationTime!.removeTrainTimeZeros()
            label.text = substation! + " " + substationTime!
            cell.ExpandableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-[label]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "expandable": cell.ExpandableView]))
            if (previousLabel == nil){
                cell.ExpandableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(10)-[label]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "expandable": cell.ExpandableView]))
            }
            else {
                cell.ExpandableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[previousLabel]-(10)-[label]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "previousLabel": previousLabel as Any]))
            }
            previousLabel = label

            }
```

Question is - why it's not resizing the view height according to the constraints? :)

Comment: Why don't you use a UITableView and put one UILabel in each cell, the auto layout on the UILabel will resize according to the uilabel text height.

Comment: Which iOS version are you planning to target? This seems as a perfect use case for a `UIStackView`.

Comment: @crizzis minimum iOS version is iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

or

```
cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

after `lor`.